# ElasticSearch 7.10.1 with Docker reports java.net.UnknownHostException under Mac but not on Linux

Tags: macos, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Hi have the following docker-compose file with several services including ElasticSearch with two nodes:

```
version: '3'
services:
  CO_MYSQL:
    image: mysql:8.0.23
    container_name: CO_MYSQL
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 72EkBqCs!
    volumes:
      - /opt/cropontology/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - CO_Network  
  CO_MONGO:
    image: mongo:3.6.8
    container_name: CO_MONGO
    volumes:
      - /opt/cropontology/mongo/data:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - CO_Network
  CO_NEO4J:
    image: neo4j:4.1.2
    container_name: CO_NEO4J
    volumes:
      - /opt/cropontology/neo4j/data:/data
      - /opt/cropontology/neo4j/plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 7687:7687
    networks:
      - CO_Network
  CO_ES_01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: CO_ES_01
    environment:
      - node.name=CO_ES_01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=CO_ES_02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=CO_ES_01,CO_ES_02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/cropontology/es/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - CO_Network
  CO_ES_02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.1
    container_name: CO_ES_02
    environment:
      - node.name=CO_ES_02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=CO_ES_01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=CO_ES_01,CO_ES_02
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - /opt/cropontology/es/data2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - CO_Network
networks:
  CO_Network:
    driver: bridge
```

Everything works well under Linux but if I try to run the same file under Mac I get:

```
CO_ES_01    | "stacktrace": ["java.net.UnknownHostException: CO_ES_02",
```

Do I need specific configuration under Mac for it to work?

Comment: You're running into a race condition. It's not guaranteed that `CO_ES_02` will start before `CO_ES_01` tries to communicate with it

Comment: Are you using the same compose file on both machines? You didn't specify the ports for `CO_ES_2`, and you also need to specify the port `9300` for both of your nodes, this is the port for the communication between nodes.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am basing my compose on Oficial Documentation for a multi-cluster where there is race condition but eventually, all nodes get connected: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file. The race condition is not causing the problem here.

Comment: @leandrojmp I am basing my compose on Oficial Documentation for a multi-cluster where the port for secondary nodes is not defined and port 9300 is not required: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-compose-file. Since the official compose file works fine in Linux but not in Mac I think the missing ports are not causing the problem here.

Comment: "but eventually, all nodes get connected" is exactly a race condition. `CO_ES_01` knows it wants to cluster with `CO_ES_02`, but that service hasn't started yet. Similarly, `CO_ES_02` uses `CO_ES_01` as a seed host, but does not wait for it to start and does not `depends_on` for it to begin bootup beforehand... You have a cyclic dependency and things are working as expected

Comment: You are right, you do not need to expose the port `9300`, my mistake. Does your nodes connect with each other after a while or they do not connect? Also, Docker on Mac works differently from Docker on Linux, on Mac you have an extra layer of virtualization that could slow down things.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it seems that the problem is the capitalization of CO_ES_0X. I changed it into coes01 and coes02 and all works fine in both Linux and Mac.